# Java Servlet and GWT service don't share session upon first request

Tags: java, session, gwt, servlets

I have GWT application with file upload Servlet.
GWT application needs to know upload progress and requests it asynchronously using GWT service.

HttpSession object gets created for the first time during the first file upload.
Right after that frontend requests upload status using GWT service, which accesses it using the following code:

```
public class ProgressServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements ProgressService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public List<ProgressChangeEvent> getProgressEvents(String progressName) {
        HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(false);
        System.out.println("Session in ProgressService: " + String.valueOf(session != null ? session.getId() : null));
        return (session != null) ? Progress.getProgressEvents(session, progressName) : null;
    }
}
```

During entire upload process the session is null.
However, the next time I upload a file the right session is there.

If I call getSession(true), it doesn't help the first time and the next time the first object is just lost, so I believe getSession(false) in this case is the right method to call, however it doesn't sync the session for quite some time.

Is it a bug or is it a desired behavior? If it's doing it by design, how can I work around it to make sure I always have upload status readily available in an asynchronous way?

Comment: Can you post also the upload servlet code?

Comment: Upload servlet code is quite convoluted due to the use of special streams, etc. What matters though is that it calls HttpSession session = request.getSession(); without any synchronizations. Session Id is always the same, which suggests that session object is created only once.

Comment: So are you getting a null session or a null progress? In the upload servlet which progressName are you using to store the progress? Are you passing it as GET/POST parameter?

Comment: If I call request.getSession(false), then I get null session first time and non-null session created in UploadServlet all other times. If I call request.getSession() (same as request.getSession(true)), then I get newly created session, which gets replaced by the one that was created first in UploadServlet. In the second scenario Progress is null first time because session is new.

Answer (score 2):

A GWT Service *is* a servlet. It will behave like any other servlet.

Your bug appears to be in this line:

```
HttpSession session = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(false);
```

By specifying `false` according to the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29), you've said "if a session hasn't already been started, don't bother to start one, and return null instead". Instead, specify `true` to say that you want to start a session. Then, the next request made by the app will have a session, which was made in this request.

Comment: If I call getSession(true) it will create a different session instance. That other session will not have any data that UploadServlet session has and the next request it will be replaced by that from UploadServlet.

Comment: My question is not about how to create new session object. It's about why the session doesn't get shared between servlets during first request, but gets shared the next request and if it's so by design (let's say sharing happens only after servlet's doPost() is done, then I wonder if there's a workaround for that behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Was this resolved? I have the same issue. No one provided solution, The issue is that in first time in servlet `getSession(true).getId(true)` and  in GWT `getThreadLocalRequest().getRequestedSessionId()` return different ID, but next call they are synchronized.

Comment: Andrew, this was such a long time ago I simply do not remember how it was fixed. However, I remember I made it work and even created a simple library to use for progress bar. Let me know if you need that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a unique situation that might have caused the problem.  If you have your web.xml set up like so:

```
<session-config>
   <cookie-config>
       <secure>true</secure>
   </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

but you're not using https on your test system, GWT will create a new session for every request since it isn't getting the cookies it needs to preserve the session.  Something like this shouldn't happen in a production environment (or any other environment if it's set up right) but I thought I'd mention it because I've run into it, and it's hard to discover what is causing the problem through debugging.

Answer (score 1):

If you call the `getSession` method without a parameter, it has the following behavior  :

```
Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.
```

It's in principle the same behavior as if you call `getSession(true)`. Calling `getSession(false)` will never create a session that you can use.

Comment: That's clear. What's not clear is why the session object doesn't get propagated to another servlet at the first time and gets there the next request.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by adding RPC call first, before calling servlet that has to read the session ID. RPC call just create new session and than call to servlet is sent in the same session scope. Hope it helps to some one else using GWT in old projects.